# Writing "リー" in Foreign Name

Tags: translation

Hello my question regarding transliterating foreign names in Japanese with リー, really anything with an "i" that is followed by a long vowel.   I was wondering what might be valid transliterations .  When transliterating リー, would "i", or "ii", or even "ee" be valid?  Is the "ee" valid for the way it sounds?  I fear the answer may be "it depends", but I figure I might ask for the heck of it see if there are some things to look for.

ウォンリーク.  Wonrik, Wonriik, Wonreek?

Comment: That is called "transliteration" and not "translation".  You don't translate people's names.

Comment: Ok thank you for the correction. Will correct it in the question.  Cannot change the tag since I do not have 300 reputation though apparently.

Comment: @MikeZ Are you taking about り or い？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It depends..."

In (English pronunciations of certain) names, the sound `/i/ ~ /iː/` is represented in a number of different orthographies:

- St**e**ven
- L**i**sa
- **Y**vonne
- Soph**ie**
- Ph**oe**be
- Lac**ey**
- L**ee**
- L**eah**
- Lou**is**
- Finl**ay**

An (mostly) unambiguous transliteration would be *ee*, as the others are often representative of other sounds as well in English (e.g. *i, y* `/ɪ/`, *ie* `/aɪ/`, *ey, ay* `/eɪ/`).

---

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_orthography#Vowels_2